# How to fix tecno spark 7 PR651 struck at boot animation?

Tags: recovery-mode, boot, frp

I was trying an experiment on bypassing factory reset protection(FRP) on my Tecno Spark 7 F6317 PR651 Android 11. I bypassed the setup screen enter chrome and download Google Account Manager(GAM) and FRP bypass apk and install them, opened frp bypass apk and enter the bypass google account after that I try to go back to the setup screen like we normally do on Android 10 but unfortunate for me the phone rebooted by itself and get stuck at the boot animation.

And badly it refuses to enter recovery mode. I have tried if not all but most boot series:

Volume Up + Power Key

Volume Down + Power Key

Volume Down + Power Key then release Power Key

Volume Up + Power Key then release Power Key

**Note: It is running on Unisoc(SoC) Processor**

Comment: It is running on Unisoc(SoC) processor.

Comment: try spreadtrum frp remove tool